# SCP from an EC2 instance to another EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, scp

I created an ssh key on one of the EC2 instances with Ubuntu AMI, and I want to copy this key to the other instance.
I used the following command to do so:

```
sudo scp -i "node11.pem" -r ~/.ssh ubuntu@3.225.77.203:home/
```

Where "node11.pem" is the private key of both of the EC2 instances, saved in the directory I'm executing the previous command from.
I keep getting this error:

```
ubuntu@3.225.77.203: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

I have all ports open for TCP, UDP, ICMP. I don't understand why it keeps showing this error.

Comment: Why are you using sudo?

Comment: this question has nothing to do with AWS or even with ubuntu. your `node11.pem` doesn't match the public key that you selected when you launched the other instance. voting to close as belonging on another Stack Exchange site

Comment: And in fact, as I mentioned, node11.pem is the key I selected for both instances.